# How do i use coreui?

Tags: javascript, html, css, core-ui

I am trying to use coreui for a project im starting but for somereasson it dosent work I tried using the template the site gives and I cant get it to work. Am I doing something wrong or am I forgeting something?

`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CoreUI CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/browse/@coreui/coreui@2.1.16/dist/css/coreui.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body class="app">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          1/2
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          1/2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          1/3
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          1/3
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          1/3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, Bootstrap, then CoreUI  -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/@coreui/coreui@2.1.16/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

I tried following the tutorial on the page but i couldnt get coreui to work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not really saying anything.

Comment: my bad, i mean i cant get the css from coreui or the javascript functions to work, it just shows the site in plain text